# How to convert a string representation of 'bytes' to its corresponding 'utf-8' in Python? (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, utf-8, byte

The bytes data is stored as a string in a variable.

Eg: x = "\x61\x62\x63"

I need to convert this to its corresponding UTF-8. (In this case "abc").

I tried to convert it to bytes and then decode it, but the result was the input itself.

Comment: It is unclear what you have.  `print(ascii(x))` so we can see the *exact* content of the string.  For example `'\x61\x62\x63' == 'abc'` so that isn't what you actually have.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> x = "\x61\x62\x63"
>>> x
'abc'
>>> bytes(x, 'utf-8')
b'abc'
>>> str(bytes(x, 'utf-8'))[2:-1]
'abc'
```

Comment: Im getting "\\x61\\x62\\x63" itself as the result.

Comment: Strange, are you typing in exactly what I am? And what version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Even though, I would not recommend to use `eval` in production, you could do the following:

```py
import ast
x = r"\x61\x62\x63"
code = 'b"{0}"'.format(x)
b = ast.literal_eval(code)
b.decode('utf-8')
```

Edit:
IIRC, the format string came with a later python version, so use
`'b"{0}".format(x)'`.

Edit: Added comment by Mark Tolonen.

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` as a safer alternative to `eval`.